# Give background property with variable

Tags: jquery, html, css

Give background image size in percentage like below , but 80% or suppose var pix="300px"  is store in variable then how to give that backgroun size property .

```
image.style.backgroundSize="100% 80%";
```

i tried

```
 image.style.backgroundSize="100% +h+'%';
```

but this is not working .

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Pekka something like image.style.backgroundSize="100% +h+'%';   where hcontains 80

Comment: So calculate 80% of 300px (`300 / 100 * 80`, then round) and set that as a pixel value?